# Windows 10 Upgrade won’t start, how long does it take?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I got a new laptop with Windows 8.1 OEM installed.

On one of first run screens I was asked if I want to upgrade to Windows 10. I clicked on `Upgrade` button and some time after I saw Win8 startup screen and not a sign of preparing to upgrade.

How long should I wait for the Windows 10 Upgrade to start?

Comment: It should happen within a reasonable amount of time.  It sounds like the upgrade process never started and/or failed.  I suggest simply using the Media Creation Tool instead and starting the upgrade manually.

Comment: @Ramhound, will it erase previously installed SW and drivers?

Comment: Only if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making sure that you have completed the latest updates on Windows 8.1 before upgrading. I would also check to make sure you have enough adequate amount of space on your hard drive, check the event log in System Tools to make sure you do not have any error message in the logs at time, or before the upgrade.